# Cut of middle word from a string python

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I am trying to cut of few words from the scraped data.

```
3 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery
```

There are many rows of data like this. I am trying to remove the word 'Bedroom' from the string. I am using beautiful soup and python to scrape the webpage, and here I am using this

```
for eachproperty in properties:
 print eachproperty.string[2:]
```

I know what the above code will do. But I cannot figure out how to just remove the "Bedroom" which is between 3 and ,Residen....

Comment: So what exactly should the result be?

Comment: `eachproperty.string = eachproperty.string.replace('Bedroom', '')`

Comment: I want it to be `3, Residential Apartment in Velachery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re   
>>> strs = "3 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery"
>>> re.sub(r'\s*Bedroom\s*', '', strs)
'3, Residential Apartment in Velachery'
```

or:

```
>>> strs.replace(' Bedroom', '')
'3, Residential Apartment in Velachery'
```

Note that strings are immutable, so you need to assign the result off `re.sub` and `str.replace` to a variable.

Comment: I just tried `eachproperty.string.replace(' Bedroom','')` . It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `replace` method:

```
line = "3 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery"
line = line.replace("Bedroom", "")

# For multiple lines use a for loop
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("Bedroom", "")
```

Comment: @Amyth That still won't do anything inside the loop. The point is you need to replace the string object wherever you're getting the original from. And it's pretty clear from the OP's code that it's not a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is

```
k = input_string.split()
if "Bedroom" in k:
  k.remove("Bedroom")
answer = ' '.join(k)
```

This won't handle punctuation like in your question.  To do that you need

```
rem = "Bedroom"
answer = ""
for i in range(len(input_string)-len(rem)):
   if (input_string[i:i+len(rem)]==rem):
     answer = input_string[:i]+input_string[i+len(rem)]
     break
```

Comment: There's no built-in function named `split()`.